# php cron = php cli script?

Tags: php, cron, command-line-interface

I need to write a php script that needs to be executed every 10 mins, so I'm going to setup as a cron job like this:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /path/to/my/file.php
```

According to:
[Running php script as cron job - timeout issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352388/running-php-script-as-cron-job-timeout-issues)

there is no timeout for command line script, which means when running cli script set_time_limit doesn't need to be extended

I have a few questions regarding this:

1. if I run my php using: */10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /path/to/my/file.php, will file.php become an command line script (which means it won't timeout)?
2. do I have to add line: #!/usr/bin/php -q inside file.php?
3. according to: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php I have to make sure cli is enabled (--enable-cli) so is it mean that if php is running as cgi (ie. fastcgi) or cli is not enabled (--disable-cli) then I can't setup any cron at all?

Please advise.

Comment: Worth noting that many shared hosts still kill processes that run for too long, regardless of the presence or absence of `set_time_limit`.

Answer (score 2):

/usr/local/bin/php 
this runs your php file
1) it dont have timeout
2) no
3) if php runs in command line your cron will run.