# Running large PHP script as cron job in background to avoid 503 error

Tags: php, bash, apache, cron

I have a PHP script `editxml.php` that combines an array of XML files using a couple foreach loops. It works fines with 4 or 5 files but if I try 20 files then the server times out and I receive a 503 error. The script outputs one XML file that is saved in the same directory, but nothing needs to be visible in the browser. How can I run this in the background until it finishes?

```
$fileout = 'output.xml';
$dst = simplexml_load_file( 'template.xml' );
$dst = dom_import_simplexml( $dst )->ownerDocument;
$parent = $dst->getElementsByTagName( 'root' )->item(0);

$files = array(
"1.xml", // desc
"2.xml", // desc
"3.xml", // desc
"4.xml", // desc
"5.xml", // desc
"6.xml", // desc


);  

foreach ($files as $xml) {

$src = simplexml_load_file($xml);

    foreach( $src->product as $product )
  {
      $node = dom_import_simplexml( $product );
      $node = $dst->importNode( $node, 1 );
      $parent->appendChild( $node );
  }
}

$final = new DOMDocument();
$final->loadXML( $dst->saveXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$final->formatOutput = True;
echo $final->saveXML();
$fh = fopen( $fileout, 'w') or die ( "can't open file $fileout" );
fwrite( $fh, $final->saveXML() );
fclose( $fh );
```

I'm using a digitalocean ubuntu 14.04 droplet with serverpilot but anything that requires shell/bash or remote ssh or PATH changes is extremely difficult for me so I'd like to avoid that if possible. I know the path but connecting PHP and shell remotely, etc... is not my strong point.

`* 15 * * * /opt/sp/php5.6/bin/php -f /path/to/trigger.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Will running a cron job to a `trigger.php` file that triggers the `editxml.php` file keep the script running in the background? Inside `trigger.php` is:
`exec("/path/to/editxmltest.php > /dev/null &");`

Comment: Readers may wish to know that this question [has been x-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/4a9l48/best_practices_for_running_a_large_php_script_in/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More information on the fix on this subreddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/4a9l48/best_practices_for_running_a_large_php_script_in/

I ended up manually running it from the command line as a logged in user, I will worry about automating the process later on but the PHP process completed successfully and output the file to the correct directory. The command that I used was

`nohup php -q /path/to/test.php > /path/to/process_log.xml 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 0):

Seems your server getting time-out on execution. Increase your execution time by adding below code at the top of your code

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

You can also increase on php.ini ([Refer](https://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set))

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Please check on the below thread for best practices,

[Running php script as cron job - timeout issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352388/running-php-script-as-cron-job-timeout-issues)

Comment: Thanks, I did previously try with `set_time_limit(0);
 ignore_user_abort(true);` but didn't have any luck. I guess I will have to edit the php.ini file. I will report back once I've done that.

Comment: Derek, While executing the code without cron. Did its working fine ?

Comment: If I scale it down to 3 or 4 files yes but when I increase it it times out. I forgot that serverpilot makes it tougher than usual to access your php.ini file so I will have to contact them about this.

Comment: Derek, Trying Changing on php.ini and verify it on phpinfo(), Let me know it solves. Good Luck !!

Comment: I did change the PHP.ini file following these instructions but it doesn't seems to work: https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-change-max_execution_time.html

What if this is a REALLY big operation? Final output file will be 500mb unzipped. Is there a completely more efficient way of running a process this big?

Comment: Did you check phpinfo() that the changes reflected

Comment: yes, if you check the Reddit link that halfer posted above you will see that it is more a problem with running the command without the browser. There is no way I will not got a 503 error if using the browser, the file is simple too big right now.